# Why dos TSLint only checks src directory?

Tags: typescript, tslint

Why dos TSLint only checks src directory?

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "typings"]
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*", "./typings/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

tslint.json

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {},
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Check the whole project

it only shows errors of src directory

```sh
tslint --project .

ERROR: /Users/kiwenlau/Desktop/tslint-test/src/index.ts:1:1 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
```

Check src directory

```sh
tslint "src/**/*"

ERROR: src/index.ts:1:1 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
```

Check typings directory

```sh
tslint "typings/**/*"

ERROR: typings/index.d.ts:1:11 - interface name must start with a capitalized I
```

please check [kiwenlau/tslint-test](https://github.com/kiwenlau/tslint-test) for source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3966), TSLint ignores `.d.ts` files when processing the `include` paths from `tsconfig.json`.

Unfortunately, TSLint is not in development anymore so this will never be changed. The official suggestion is to use ESLint with typescript-eslint instead. You can read more about that in [this blog post](https://medium.com/palantir/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9).

---

If you'd like to keep using TSLint for the time being, you could specify both paths when calling it like this:

```
tslint "src/**/*" "typings/**/*"
```

Or a bit shorter like this:

```
tslint "{src,typings}/**/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if this issue

```
TSLint ignores .d.ts files when processing the include paths from tsconfig.json.
```

mentioned in the answer above was fixed or another linter was used, still the file `./typings/index.d.ts` can be ignored by any linter which, like Typescript compiler, considers it to be a [possible output](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details) file in presense of the `src/index.ts`.

Executing `tslint "typings/**/*"` takes `src/index.ts` out of the consideration so the file `./typings/index.d.ts` cannot be ignored anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When using the [TSLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin) extension of Visual Studio Code, we can solve the problem by just set `tslint.ignoreDefinitionFiles` as `false`.